# How to eagerly load multiple related models in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have a relationships as follows:

An `Order` has many `Product`s, and a `Product` has many `Order`s.

```
class Order extends Model {
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

A `Product` has many `Image`s, and an `Image` belongs to a `Product`.

```
class Product extends Model {
    ...
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }
}
```

For an order `$order`, I can load its products as `$order->load('products')`, but how do I eagerly load the `images` of the products for this `$order`?

Comment: Have you tried `$order->load('products.images')`?

Comment: I did now. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, you can simply do `$order->load('products.images')` or also add the property  `$with = ['images']` to the `Product` model/entity.

Comment: If I add `$with = ['images']` to `Product`, would it load the images every time  I select products?

Comment: Yes, `$with`  can be tricky, I have an app with 50+ entities, in this case `$with` will end up being a relationship nightmare trap.